# No output on the codepen after render my component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, codepen

I am using codepen.io to start with reactjs for the sample program. Below are my complete code. Not sure why the RenderDOM is not rendering the component correctly

**HTML**

```
    <div class="person">
    <h1> Raj </h1>
    <p> Age 27 </p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .person{
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    }
```

**JS (Babel)**

```
    function Person()
    {
    return
    (
        <div className="person">
            <h1> Nandhi </h1>
            <p> Age 27 </p>
        </div> 
    );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Person />,
    document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

**Attached the screenshot here:**
[image]

Comment: can you provide the codepen link?

Comment: Can you try using document.getElementById('p1') instead of document.querySelector('#p1')?

Comment: @TarunDugar The link of his codepen : https://codepen.io/Nandy264129/pen/JzzBVd

Comment: @Shaubam Zanwar - Removing the # symbol is not helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the return statement inside `Person`:

```
return 
(
)
```

Change it to:

```
return (
)
```

JavaScript returns `undefined` if there is nothing at the end of `return` indicating that the expression is running to the next line.

Comment: Thanks @Tarun. Its fine now :)

Comment: happy to help! :)